# Nested async db call in for loop, wait until loop is done

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am using the `listCollection` method in mongodb and looping through each returned collection with a query using `find`.

The problem is that I use the loop to construct an object that I wish to return with `response.json` after the loop is done but since `find` is async I am stuck at figuring how to "wait" until every `find` callback has finished before returning `response.json()`

```
var data = {};

database.listCollections({name: {$ne: 'system.indexes'}}).toArray(function(err, collections) {
    if (err) return res.json({});

    for(i=0; i<collections.length; i++){
        var collection = collections[i].name;

        database.collection(collection).find(query, limit)
        .sort({"Date": -1}).toArray(function(err, docs){

            if (err) return res.json({
            });

               /* Do stuff with docs, push stuff to data */
        });
        /** Console shows blank **/
        console.log("Data " + i+ ": " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  /** Response is blank.. **/
  res.json(data);
});
```

The problem is that the for loop returns way before the `find()`s are done. How do I deal with this in a `JS`/`Node` way? I can hack together a solution but I might encounter a similar problem later..

Edit: I am certain that data is actually returned and processed properly, as a `console.log()` inside each find on data shows that it actually has content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if your NodeJS version supports it or use any Promise library otherwise. In this case you can wrap your code inside `for` loop into some function that returns `Promise`, then push all those promises objects into array. After loop call

`Promise.all(promisesArray).then(/* Callback function that sends response */)`

Another option is to use recursion instead of `for` loop and send request when you reach stop condition. But I don't think it's good option because in case if `collections` array is big you can exceed maximum stack size.